# Increase azure data explorer query limit inside stored procedure

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql, kusto-explorer

In azure data explorer DB I have defined procedure which should move aggregated data from one table into other DB table.
While running procedure following limit is being hit, E_RUNAWAY_QUERY _ message:

> Aggregation over string column exceeded the memory budget of 8GB
> during evaluation

currently I can not decrease size of data transferred and wanted to use workaround option by increasing limits with `set truncationmaxsize=...`  but when I try to include this order in stored procedure, sp fails during altering.
Is it possible to use limit increasing commands (like `set truncationmaxsize=1048576`) inside stored procedures or not, if this is possible how?

Answer (score 0):

You can override those default memory limit consumption as per [**Limit on memory per iterator**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/concepts/querylimits#limit-on-memory-per-iterator) and [**Limit on memory per node**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/concepts/querylimits#limit-on-memory-per-node).

The best way of approach would be splitting the result into multiple ones using **(.set, .append, .set-or-append)**  you can refer [**query best practices**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/best-practices) and [**Ingest from query**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/data-ingestion/ingest-from-query).